# Compiling Bitcoin Core v0.10.0 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: bitcoin-core, ubuntu, compiling

I'm trying to compile Bitcoin Core v0.10.0 on Ubuntu 20.04, but then I get the following error:

```
rpcserver.cpp: In function ‘void StartRPCThreads()’:
rpcserver.cpp:594:77: error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::asio::ssl::context::context(boost::asio::io_service&, boost::asio::ssl::context_base::method)’
  594 |     rpc_ssl_context = new ssl::context(*rpc_io_service, ssl::context::sslv23);
      |                                                                             ^
In file included from /usr/include/boost/asio/ssl/context.hpp:757,
                 from /usr/include/boost/asio/ssl.hpp:18,
                 from rpcprotocol.h:16,
                 from rpcserver.h:10,
                 from rpcserver.cpp:6:
/usr/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:371:1: note: candidate: ‘boost::asio::ssl::context::context(boost::asio::ssl::context&&)’
  371 | context::context(context&& other)
      | ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:371:1: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
/usr/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:63:1: note: candidate: ‘boost::asio::ssl::context::context(boost::asio::ssl::context_base::method)’
   63 | context::context(context::method m)
      | ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:63:1: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
rpcserver.cpp:613:50: error: ‘class boost::asio::ssl::context’ has no member named ‘impl’
  613 |         SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(rpc_ssl_context->impl(), strCiphers.c_str());
      |                                                  ^~~~
rpcserver.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void RPCListen(boost::shared_ptr >, boost::asio::ssl::context&, bool) [with Protocol = boost::asio::ip::tcp; SocketAcceptorService = boost::asio::executor]’:
rpcserver.cpp:673:58:   required from here
rpcserver.cpp:482:111: error: ‘class boost::asio::basic_socket_acceptor’ has no member named ‘get_io_service’
  482 |     boost::shared_ptr > conn(new AcceptedConnectionImpl(acceptor->get_io_service(), context, fUseSSL));
      |                                                                                                     ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from primitives/block.h:9,
                 from chainparams.h:11,
                 from base58.h:17,
                 from rpcserver.cpp:8:
./primitives/transaction.h: In instantiation of ‘static _OI std::__copy_move::__copy_m(_II, _II, _OI) [with _II = const CTxOut*; _OI = CTxOut*]’:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algobase.h:404:30:   required from ‘_OI std::__copy_move_a(_II, _II, _OI) [with bool _IsMove = false; _II = const CTxOut*; _OI = CTxOut*]’
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algobase.h:441:30:   required from ‘_OI std::__copy_move_a2(_II, _II, _OI) [with bool _IsMove = false; _II = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >; _OI = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >]’
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algobase.h:474:7:   required from ‘_OI std::copy(_II, _II, _OI) [with _II = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >; _OI = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >]’
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/vector.tcc:238:31:   required from ‘std::vector& std::vector::operator=(const std::vector&) [with _Tp = CTxOut; _Alloc = std::allocator]’
coins.h:90:19:   required from here
./primitives/transaction.h:103:7: warning: implicitly-declared ‘CScript& CScript::operator=(const CScript&)’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-copy]
  103 | class CTxOut
      |       ^~~~~~
In file included from ./primitives/transaction.h:10,
                 from primitives/block.h:9,
                 from chainparams.h:11,
                 from base58.h:17,
                 from rpcserver.cpp:8:
./script/script.h:365:5: note: because ‘CScript’ has user-provided ‘CScript::CScript(const CScript&)’
  365 |     CScript(const CScript& b) : std::vector(b.begin(), b.end()) { }
      |     ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/algorithm:61,
                 from serialize.h:9,
                 from amount.h:9,
                 from rpcserver.h:9,
                 from rpcserver.cpp:6:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algobase.h:342:18: note: synthesized method ‘CTxOut& CTxOut::operator=(const CTxOut&)’ first required here
  342 |        *__result = *__first;
      |        ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from chain.h:11,
                 from main.h:14,
                 from rpcserver.cpp:10:
tinyformat.h: In static member function ‘static const char* tinyformat::detail::FormatIterator::streamStateFromFormat(std::ostream&, unsigned int&, const char*, int, int)’:
tinyformat.h:785:21: warning: this statement may fall through [-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
  785 |             out.setf(std::ios::uppercase);
      |             ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
tinyformat.h:786:9: note: here
  786 |         case 'x': case 'p':
      |         ^~~~
tinyformat.h:791:21: warning: this statement may fall through [-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
  791 |             out.setf(std::ios::uppercase);
      |             ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
tinyformat.h:792:9: note: here
  792 |         case 'e':
      |         ^~~~
tinyformat.h:797:21: warning: this statement may fall through [-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
  797 |             out.setf(std::ios::uppercase);
      |             ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
tinyformat.h:798:9: note: here
  798 |         case 'f':
      |         ^~~~
tinyformat.h:802:21: warning: this statement may fall through [-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
  802 |             out.setf(std::ios::uppercase);
      |             ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
tinyformat.h:803:9: note: here
  803 |         case 'g':
      |         ^~~~
make[2]: *** [Makefile:3910: libbitcoin_server_a-rpcserver.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/src/bitcoin-0.10.0/src'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:6475: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/src/bitcoin-0.10.0/src'
make: *** [Makefile:569: all-recursive] Error 1
```

I followed the instructions on the *build-unix.md* file, and I believe the problem is related to the required dependencies, especially the *libboost-all-dev* package. Interestingly, I was able to compile every released version from v0.20.1 to 0.16.0, but nothing older than that, using the same instructions on *build-unix.md*. If the problem really is *libboost-all-dev* , how can I solve it?

### Update:

I've installed boost version 1.57 as Pieter suggested with:

```
tar --bzip2 -xf /path/to/boost_1_57_0.tar.bz2
cd boost_1_57_0/
./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/usr/
./b2
sudo ./b2 install
```

And then, on the bitcoin root, used:

```
./configure --with-boost-liddir=LIB_DIR
```

But as result I got:

```
configure: error: Could not find a version of the boost_system library!
```

And I've tried different paths but always got the same result. Is this just path problem or is there something else?

### Update 2:

Apparently I fixed the path with:

```
./configure --with-boost-libdir=/usr/lib/
```

But when I run make I got this [error](https://pastebin.com/KmRAFg0e).

What is the problem?

Comment: You may need an older version of Boost.

Comment: Do you know which version? Or even if is there any place where I can find information about dependencie's version for specific bitcoin core's version?

Comment: For recent versions that information is in doc/dependencies.md, but that didn't exist at the time of 0.10.0. I'd just start with whatever version of Boost was most recent at the time. Bitcoin Core 0.10.0 was released in Feb 2015, so maybe 1.57 or a bit earlier?

Comment: Another aspect: Bitcoin Core was not using C++11 until 0.13.0, but your compilation output suggests you are using C++11 here. With a modern compiler you may want to explicitly disable that (`-std=c++98`).

Comment: Thanks Pieter. I will try it and update with the results.

Answer (score 1):

The two points raised in the comments are necessary to compile bitcoin core v0.10.0. First the best way to install Boost libraries in unix is described in `build_unix.md`, where in the Boost section we have

```
sudo su
./bootstrap.sh
./bjam install
```

but for v0.10.0 we need at least version 1.57 of Boost that can be found [here](https://www.boost.org/users/history/).
We will also need older versions of OpenSSL libraries, in this case I needed the packages `libssl-dev` version 1.0.1f, `libssl1.0.0` version 1.0.1f and `multiarch-support` version 2.19.

After installing the packages we can compile bitcoin core using

```
./autogen.sh
./configure --without-gui CXX="g++ -std=c++98"
make
make install
```

The flags in `configure` follow the comments for the C++ version and the absence of GUI is due to the fact that v0.10.0 will request Qt 4 packages for graphical interface which I couldn't find. Once those step are followed bitcoin core will be successfully compiled.